# Finding the nucleus of neutron capture in geant4

Tags: geant4

I am shooting neutrons to  gadolinium mix with water. I want to count how many neutron captured on hydrogen and gadolinium.  I have found a question as [Find nucleus involved in nCapture process in Geant4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6244336/18348296)
Answer given here this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18934601/18348296 . Could anyone say how  these two classes myParticle and myMC will look like? Or is this necessary to construct these two data classes ?

How can I count the number of neutron captured on gadolinium and hydrogen?